# Почему при кадрировании картинки со свечением появляется рамка и как ее убрать?

Tags: html, css, css3, изображения

[image: картинка 1][image: картинка 2]

Есть картинка со свечением, которая расположена на полупрозрачном фоне. Чтобы нивелировать отступы, я кадрирую большую из них в фотошопе и уменьшаю в размере за счет обрезки по краям (высоте и ширине) - в таком случае появляется вокруг изображения полупрозрачная рамка. Задача такая: как сохранить у картинки исходный размер, но при этом убрать у нее пустые отупы с каждой из сторон?

```css
#main {
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(159, 105, 94, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0 -20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img src="http://s019.radikal.ru/i632/1611/ad/2357375f029d.png" />
  <img src="http://s09.radikal.ru/i182/1611/cc/fcaf7b157f62.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: картинка потому что такая...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы обрезаете свечение вот и получается такая рамка. Попробуйте использовать отрицательные значения для `margin`.

```css
#main {
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(159, 105, 94, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0 -20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.pic {
  margin-right: -30px; /* например: убираем отступ с права*/
  }
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img class="pic" src="http://s019.radikal.ru/i632/1611/ad/2357375f029d.png" />
  <img src="http://s09.radikal.ru/i182/1611/cc/fcaf7b157f62.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: да, отрицательный `margin` решает, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```css
#main {
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(159, 105, 94, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0 -20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
#pic2{
width:100px;
  height:130px;

}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img src="http://s019.radikal.ru/i632/1611/ad/2357375f029d.png" />
  <img id='pic2' src="http://s019.radikal.ru/i632/1611/ad/2357375f029d.png" />
</div>
```

**UPD**

```css
#main {
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(159, 105, 94, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0 -20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
#pic2{
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img src="http://s019.radikal.ru/i632/1611/ad/2357375f029d.png" />
  <img id='pic2' src="http://s019.radikal.ru/i632/1611/ad/2357375f029d.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: да, размерами можно задать, но она уменьшилась. а мне нужно сохранить размеры, но при этом убрать отступы - дополню в описание

Comment: @Вася тогда надо заново фотошопить картинку, т.к. ваша обрезана по полупрозрачному фону поэтому и выделяется 'обрезка'...

Comment: @Вася можно по другому, посмотрите 'UPD'

Comment: да, абсолютное позиционирование - это костыль, который выбивает картинку с потока и накладывает много ограничений в моем случает. внизу дали самый правильный ответ - использовать отрицательные `margin`. а что вы имели ввиду под "заново фотошопить картинку" ?